# Is it possible to make an image link to an external link in Apple News Format?

Tags: apple-news

I'm new to Apple News Format and was asked to place a banner on our Apple News articles that links to our external website on a browser.

But I'm not seeing a way to do so. I'm using the [Image](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_news/image) component, which supports additions for [ComponentLinks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_news/componentlink), which are for internal links only.

Does anyone know of a workaround? It seems like only [Text](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_news/text) components support external links (via [LinkAdditions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_news/linkaddition)), so I'm not sure if it's just not feasible with an image or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Wasn't able to make an image with an external link work but the workaround we used was to use an image as the background using an ImageFill in a wrapper container and a body component with html format and a link inside. You can format the text inside the link by using `<span data-anf-textstyle="myStyle">` tags and setting the styles in the `textStyles` configuration.